# Saving a Session attribute through JSF

Tags: jsf, session

How can I store in database an user Session attribute along with other informations provided in the same form?

```
<p:outputLabel value="user ID:" for="informer" />
<p:inputText id="informer" value="#{session.getAttribute('userID').toString()}" 
 title="informer" disabled="true" />
```

Only the Session attribute is saved as NULL, though it appears in the form field. The other fields are saved properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `disabled` attributes aren't considered by HTML/JSF form submissions. Do you really need to display the value?

Comment: Hi Mabi. I've already tested, with enbled or disabled, and got the same result after saving that field: NULL. Yes, I really need to display the value. Thanks.

Comment: mabi, I've tested your solution and it works. Thanks. But I've formulated this question not the way I needed to expose my concrete problem. I really appreciate if you could take a look at the following (reformulated) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485601/storing-user-session-attributes-through-jsf-selected-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised your JSF implementation isn't throwing an error about this, because `value` attributes for input components need to be writeable - and the string produced by `.toString()` clearly isn't.

The way forward is to set the value to the field that's actually gonna hold the data:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private String userId;
    //... other fields
}

@Named @ViewScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    private User myUser;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        String uid = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getSessionMap().get("userID").toString();
        myUser = new User();
        myUser.setUserId(uid);
    }
}
```

And in your view:

```
<p:outputLabel value="user ID:" for="informer" />
<p:inputText id="informer" value="#{userBean.myUser.userId}" disabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll ignore the design problem here (this is already pointed out by mabi) and I'll just straight answer the concrete question: just refer the session map as available by `#{sessionScope}`.

```
<p:inputText ... value="#{sessionScope.userID}" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, for the sole purpose of printing it to the output, don't use:

```
#{session.getAttribute('userID').toString()}
```

This doesn't make any sense. Just refer it the usual EL way:

```
#{userID}
```

Comment: BalusC, if you didn't said that, probably I'd never change the way I was doing, because, besides the horrendous and nonsense I was using, it worked. Blessed be whom taught me well.